# Linux User Previlages to change Owner/Group

Tags: linux, unix

I have some files, for which user is nobody and group is nogroup.
How do i set user privileges so that my user can change user and group to myself.
I don't want to do it using root or sudo.

Thanks

Comment: You can't. If you could arbitrarily change owner and group using a non-privileged user account that would defeat the purpose of file permissions. Why are you against using root or sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `owner` of a file/directory can change permissions of the file/directory.

`root/sudo` can access any file/directory and modify any file/directory 's permissions.

So to answer your question only the users `nobody` and `root` can change the file/directory 's permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Let me brief the permissions part a bit for you:
1. Changing the ownership of any file or folder can only be done by root.
2. Only the owner of the file/folder can change the group.

So, in your case you'll need root or sudo rights for performing those actions.
Hope it helps